# can we use GLPK and JuMP package in GPU program of Julia

Tags: julia, gpu, julia-jump, glpk

I have one CPU runnable in julia program in that program i have applied constaraint on array that the elements which are greater than one and 4 is completely divisible by that elements store such elements on model using GLPK and JuMP package , so i want to convert that CPU runnable code into GPU runnable

I just want solution that can we use GLPK and JuMP package in GPU program of julia .If yes then how

Comment: crosspost: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/can-we-use-glpk-library-in-gpu-programming/101697/10

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use GLPK and JuMP on a GPU.

Comment: ...and it seems that GPU is not a promising direction for LP/MILP problem - see https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012237852-Does-Gurobi-support-GPUs-